# How to make a timer keep on ticking when window is closed

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a javascript timer keep on going even when the window is closed?
Can I save these things with localstorage somehow?

Could anyone please explain how I would do this?

For example:

When someone pushes a button on my website, I want to make this button disabled for an hour.

```
setTimeOut(func, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Now that timer will of course stop when I leave the page. However, I want it to continue ticking if someone leaves the actual page.

Comment: that doesn't make much sense, explained this way. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to save the current value of the timer each time it updates, and then read that value next time the page is reopened and if necessary make some adjustment based on the current time. But you can't have it continue to update during the time when the page is closed - after the page/window is closed the user may exit the browser, or turn off their computer, or...

Answer (score 2):

Store the timestamp (+new Date or Date.now) at the time the user pressed the button in localStorage. Read it immediately on page load and, if Date.now() - timestampInLocalStorage is positive, setTimeout(enableButton, delta) else enableButton immediately.

Note that users can tinker with their local time to bypass this protection of course.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to do, there's the new **[Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)** that can execute tasks even after the tab is closed. Suffice to say that browser support is only for modern browsers.

Note that running code after the user closes the tab generally breaks your contract with the user. "When I close the tab, I don't want any more interaction with you", so make sure you communicate this to the user before attempting to register a service worker.

Answer (score 1):

Going to add on to what Madara said as an answer because I can't comment yet.

Some browsers will let you do this through the Service Work API, but a few have begun "sleeping" when a tab goes dormant such as Chrome. Chrome puts an inactive tab to sleep after being away for a short amount of time. So even if you start a counter before they leave and then somehow detect that they left the counter won't be accurate. Because of this it's really hard to get it to work across all browsers without resorting to hacks.

So it's plausible... but you really shouldn't do it. You'll spend way too much time finding work arounds. The reality is that it's in the best interest of the user to prevent this so you'll be fighting the browsers themselves.